# Why am i getting negative numbers in Fibonacci series using java

Tags: java

I have written this code to get Fibonacci numbers by inputting the size.
The results i am getting is correct but only thing i am concerned about is the negative sign for some values for higher range of size input.

1- I am unable to find the flaw in the code, how can i get rid of the negative values in the output.?
2- Why after some negative values there are positive values. 
3- First negative value is -1323752223 then a positive number follows.

Thank you.

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FibonacciSeries {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int a, c = 0;
        int result = 0;
        int b = 1;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the Number to display Fibonacci Series");
        a = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Fibonacci Seriers is as follows");


        for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++) {
            System.out.print(" "+result+" ");
            result = c + b;
            b = c;
            c = result;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Overflow is going to happen if you pick a large enough value. You should use a `BigInteger` if you need an arbitrary range of values.

Comment: Did you step through the code one line at a time in your IDE debugger? Start there.

Comment: Are values up to about 2,000,000,000 correct?

Comment: If i give size as 50 i am getting this output where the first negative is less then  2,000,000,000 is there any reason by why there are positives after  negatives ?
 0  1  1  2  3  5  8  13  21  34  55  89  144  233  377  610  987  1597  2584  4181  6765  10946  17711  28657  46368  75025  121393  196418  317811  514229  832040  1346269  2178309  3524578  5702887  9227465  14930352  24157817  39088169  63245986  102334155  165580141  267914296  433494437  701408733  1134903170  1836311903  -1323752223  512559680  -811192543

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the input value, **you likely exceeding the max value that an integer can hold**.

Integers are limited to 2^31-1, or 2,147,483,647. Once you reach that threshold, the number will wrap around and start with the minimum value, -2^31, or -2,147,483,648.

---

[Also see `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE)

Comment: my first negative value is  -1323752223 then a positive number follows.

Comment: @Jfrd Which is consistent with my answer. Fibonacci numbers grow _pretty_ fast. Look into using a `long` instead of an integer, they can hold numbers up to 2^63-1.

Comment: Why are there positive numbers following negative value ? the negative values are't consistent too, both in the case of int and long int.

Comment: Well, because `1,836,311,903 + (-1,323,752,223) = 512,559,680`, simple addition. After that, `-1,323,752,223 + 512,559,680 = -811,192,543`, which doesn't exceed the max value. Perfectly logical.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use 'if' for System.out.print to check if result is negative or positive. The reason why you are getting negative values is because int is "only" 32-bit long.

You can use long instead of int, which would make it a little bit better for Fib. sequence, but it won't solve your actual problem - negative numbers.

Here is the code:

```
for( int i = 1; i <= a; i ++ ) {
    if( result >= 0 ) {
        System.out.print(" " + result + " ");
    }
    result = c + b;
    b = c;
    c = result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to modify type of variables from 'int' to 'long int' or ' unsigned int'. Maybe high value modify the bit of sign.

Comment: using long the negative numbers are pushed far but not avoided.